# Reading incorrect json, parsing example

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am reading a sort of json, uncorrectly formatted. I've tried different parsers-and none of those fit the peculiar encoding of the format-any ideas?

I've tried several packages-but none of those are able to capture all the fields in each json register

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c187d6caf0ffa6162eb4f5c"), 

"SDKVersion" : "6.1.7", 

"aaid" : "248c3ab3-919b-4525-b6cc-2c662504235d", 

"appVersion" : "6.2.4", 

"dateTime" : ISODate("2018-12-18T04:32:55.000+0000"), 

"device" : "samsung", 

"id" : NumberInt(5712), 

"installReferrer" : "", 

"isFirstRun" : false, 

"json" : null, 

"language" : "KO", 

"mcc" : NumberInt(450), 

"mnc" : NumberInt(5), 

"model" : "SM-G885S", 

"notificationId" : NumberInt(0), 

"pixelHeight" : NumberInt(2094), 

"pixelWidth" : NumberInt(1080), 

"runningSecs" : NumberInt(0), 

"status" : "pageview", 

"udid" : "6b2be43d1f1fc05c", 

"userDoc" : "", 

"userIdGA" : "", 

"version" : "8.0.0 (26)", 

"wifi" : false, 

"pagename" : "com.mo2o.alsa.modules.passengers.presentation.form.FormPassengersActivity", 

"remoteAddr" : "223.62.215.198", 

"server" : "web26", 

"serverQueueuDateTime1" : "20181218053257", 

"serverQueueuDateTime2" : ISODate("2018-12-18T04:32:57.000+0000"), 

"apiVersion" : "2.0.0", 

"dateTime2" : "2018-12-18T13:32:55+0900"
```

}

I expect the code to correctly identify all fields and extract the badly formated json, i have over 1 million registers with this same format. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try writing emulations of all of the functions (like `ISODate()`) and then treating it as a string representation of a normal `dict` and calling `eval()` on it. Then you can leverage the Python parser to do the heavy lifting. Just make sure your functions are picky about what arguments they accept.

Comment: That could be a solution. But, i have also the problem, that in some registers,  i have the field  "additional" : {

        "sell" : "Evento de compra"

    }, which could confuse the conversion to dict, any ideas there?

Comment: Why? The Python parser will cope with a `dict` nested as a value inside another `dict`.

Comment: Just for the record: this is not "invalid json", this it just not json at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than recommend that you write yet another JSON parser, I suggest that you instead take advantage of the fact that Python is a dynamic language to turn the data you have into valid Python, and get the interpreter to parse it for you. To demonstrate that the proposal in the comment will work, try this

```
>>> NumberInt = int
>>> ObjectId = str
>>> ISODate = str      # I leave a lambda that calls time.strptime() as an exercise
>>> true = True
>>> false = False
>>> null = None
>>> mydict = eval("""{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c187d6caf0ffa6162eb4f5c"), 
"SDKVersion" : "6.1.7", 
"aaid" : "248c3ab3-919b-4525-b6cc-2c662504235d", 
"appVersion" : "6.2.4", 
"dateTime" : ISODate("2018-12-18T04:32:55.000+0000"), 
"device" : "samsung", 
"id" : NumberInt(5712), 
"installReferrer" : "", 
"isFirstRun" : false, 
"json" : null, 
"language" : "KO", 
"mcc" : NumberInt(450), 
"mnc" : NumberInt(5), 
"model" : "SM-G885S", 
"notificationId" : NumberInt(0), 
"pixelHeight" : NumberInt(2094), 
"pixelWidth" : NumberInt(1080), 
"runningSecs" : NumberInt(0), 
"status" : "pageview", 
"udid" : "6b2be43d1f1fc05c", 
"userDoc" : "", 
"userIdGA" : "", 
"version" : "8.0.0 (26)", 
"wifi" : false, 
"pagename" : "com.mo2o.alsa.modules.passengers.presentation.form.FormPassengersActivity", 
"remoteAddr" : "223.62.215.198", 
"server" : "web26", 
"serverQueueuDateTime1" : "20181218053257", 
"serverQueueuDateTime2" : ISODate("2018-12-18T04:32:57.000+0000"), 
"apiVersion" : "2.0.0", 
"dateTime2" : "2018-12-18T13:32:55+0900"
}""")
```

The `eval()` call results in:

```
>>> mydict
{'userIdGA': '', 'device': 'samsung', 'mnc': 5, 'id': 5712, 'isFirstRun': False, 'serverQueueuDateTime1': '20181218053257', 'appVersion': '6.2.4', 'serverQueueuDateTime2': '2018-12-18T04:32:57.000+0000', 'json': None, 'version': '8.0.0 (26)', 'runningSecs': 0, 'userDoc': '', 'server': 'web26', 'status': 'pageview', 'SDKVersion': '6.1.7', 'mcc': 450, 'dateTime2': '2018-12-18T13:32:55+0900', 'pixelWidth': 1080, 'notificationId': 0, 'pixelHeight': 2094, 'language': 'KO', 'udid': '6b2be43d1f1fc05c', 'wifi': False, 'aaid': '248c3ab3-919b-4525-b6cc-2c662504235d', 'apiVersion': '2.0.0', 'dateTime': '2018-12-18T04:32:55.000+0000', 'installReferrer': '', 'pagename': 'com.mo2o.alsa.modules.passengers.presentation.form.FormPassengersActivity', 'model': 'SM-G885S', '_id': '5c187d6caf0ffa6162eb4f5c', 'remoteAddr': '223.62.215.198'}
```

And to answer your question about the embedded dict:

```
>>> mydict = eval("""{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c187d6caf0ffa6162eb4f5c"),
"SDKVersion" : "6.1.7",
"aaid" : "248c3ab3-919b-4525-b6cc-2c662504235d",
"appVersion" : "6.2.4",
"dateTime2" : "2018-12-18T13:32:55+0900",
"additional" : { "sell" : "Evento de compra" }
}""")
```

This is a deliberately shortened version of your example to save space. It gives:

```
>>> mydict
{'SDKVersion': '6.1.7', 'additional': {'sell': 'Evento de compra'}, 'aaid': '248c3ab3-919b-4525-b6cc-2c662504235d', 'dateTime2': '2018-12-18T13:32:55+0900', 'appVersion': '6.2.4', '_id': '5c187d6caf0ffa6162eb4f5c'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How could this work, the last one, if i have to read around one million registers with both formats-the one with sell, and the one without?. parse each register with {}, and the apply eval to each of those?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. The `eval()` will work irrespective of whether you have an embedded `dict` or not. That was the point of the example. You apply `eval()` to *the whole input string*, and the parser takes care of any embedded `dict`s, to any level. I think you should just take a half-dozen representative examples and do exactly what I have done in the answer and see what happens. Then you can deal with any real problems that arise, rather than trying to imagine them. It's unlikely you will find a 3rd-party solution, so you need to concentrate on constructing your own.

Comment: @AndresRuizDeElv If the answer worked for you, please accept it.